# Android app hangs when referencing the back button on Secondary screen

Tags: android

I have a small app that when button presses navigates when moving from main screen to next screen this works fine, but when I added a button on the next page (to go back) it breaks.

Fun.java

```
package com.forcetechnology.OptusApp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Fun extends Activity {
OnClickListener backListener;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fun);

    Button backButtonf = (Button)findViewById(com.forcetechnology.OptusApp.R.id.backtoMainf);
    backListener = new OnClickListener()
    {           
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {        
         Intent i = new Intent();
         i.setClassName("com.forcetechnology.OptusApp", "com.forcetechnology.OptusApp.OptusAppMain");
                startActivity(i);           
        }
    };
    backButtonf.setOnClickListener(backListener);

   }

}
```

Fun.Xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >




<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/backtoMainf"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/val5" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Main.xml

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/funbutton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:background="@drawable/val5"
    android:src="@drawable/val5" />



<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/executionbutton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/funbutton"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:background="@drawable/val2"
    android:src="@drawable/val2" />



<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/performancebutton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/executionbutton"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/funbutton"
    android:background="@drawable/val3"
    android:src="@drawable/val4" />



<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/innovationbutton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/executionbutton"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:background="@drawable/val3"
    android:src="@drawable/val3" />



<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/peoplebutton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/innovationbutton"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/executionbutton"
    android:background="@drawable/val1"
    android:src="@drawable/val1" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

OPtusAppMain.java

```
    package com.forcetechnology.OptusApp;

import android.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class OptusAppMain extends Activity 
{
    OnClickListener funListener,executionListener,innovationListener,peopleListener,performanceListener;;
    TextView testView;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(com.forcetechnology.OptusApp.R.layout.main);
        ImageButton funButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(com.forcetechnology.OptusApp.R.id.funbutton);
        ImageButton executionButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(com.forcetechnology.OptusApp.R.id.executionbutton);
        ImageButton innovationButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(com.forcetechnology.OptusApp.R.id.innovationbutton);
        ImageButton peopleButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(com.forcetechnology.OptusApp.R.id.peoplebutton);
        ImageButton performanceButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(com.forcetechnology.OptusApp.R.id.performancebutton);


        funListener = new OnClickListener()
        {           
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {        
                 Intent i = new Intent();
                    i.setClassName("com.forcetechnology.OptusApp", "com.forcetechnology.OptusApp.Fun");
                    startActivity(i);           
            }
        };
        executionListener = new OnClickListener()
        {           
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {        
                 Intent i = new Intent();
                 i.setClassName("com.forcetechnology.OptusApp", "com.forcetechnology.OptusApp.Execution");
                    startActivity(i);          
            }
        };
        innovationListener = new OnClickListener()
        {           
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {        
                 Intent i = new Intent();
                 i.setClassName("com.forcetechnology.OptusApp", "com.forcetechnology.OptusApp.Innovation");
                    startActivity(i);           
            }
        };
        peopleListener = new OnClickListener()
        {           
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {        
                 Intent i = new Intent();
                 i.setClassName("com.forcetechnology.OptusApp", "com.forcetechnology.OptusApp.People");
                    startActivity(i);           
            }
        };
        performanceListener = new OnClickListener()
        {           
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {        
                 Intent i = new Intent();
                 i.setClassName("com.forcetechnology.OptusApp", "com.forcetechnology.OptusApp.Performance");
                    startActivity(i);         
            }
        };
        funButton.setOnClickListener(funListener);
        executionButton.setOnClickListener(executionListener);
        innovationButton.setOnClickListener(innovationListener);
        peopleButton.setOnClickListener(peopleListener);
        performanceButton.setOnClickListener(performanceListener);
    }




}
```

Edit: I have traced the error to this line Button backButtonf = (Button)findViewById(com.forcetechnology.OptusApp.R.id.backtoMainf); in fun.java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `onClick()` of `backListener`, just call `finish()` to go back to the previous activity.

Comment: It never reaches that line, Button backButtonf = (Button)findViewById(com.forcetechnology.OptusApp.R.id.backtoMainf); is the error line.

Comment: In your `fun.xml`, `backtoMainf` is an `ImageButton`, but in `Fun.java` you try to cast it to a `Button`. `ImageButton` does not extend `Button`, so you'll get a `ClassCastException`. To fix it, use `ImageButton` instead of `Button` in `Fun.java`. See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html

Comment: Thanks for that, totally missed it.

Answer (score 0):

Lets take an example: You have two activities "A" & "B", You start your "B" activity from "A" that means your "A" activity is in stack so there is no need to start it again, just finish your "B" activity with "finish()" method.

```
public class A extends Activity{

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

public void onAbuttonClick()

```
{
```

startActivity(new Intent(A.this,B.class));
}

}

}

public class B extends Activity
            {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.second);

}

```
public onBbuttonclick(View v)
{
```

finish();
}

```
 }
```

}